# magento module enabled but results as inactive

Tags: magento-1.7, php, database

i have enabled module from admin panel but in source code it is going to else part, what may be the reason?

Please help on this...

Comment: we didt understood, what do you mean by `in source code it is going to else part` did you checked in app/etc/modules folder ?

Comment: yes i have did it..

Comment: means you are telling modules result is not displaying in site , did you logout and login to admin , also did you cleared cache ?

Comment: i have cleared all magento caches and as well as browser's cache

Comment: which module you are using , did you checked in configuration settings ?